# How can I make a js function generic to work everywhere on my form? (DRY)

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

Sorry for my noobie question, but I have a function that works for a specific field in a large form. I understand that I could hard code every possible field, but I would like to keep my code DRY. What could I do to add this distinct functionality to each field in my form. (They all share a common class but I couldnt get that to work.)

**[My Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/whyEnBe/cwmxrn55/)**

Here is my HTML

```
<form id="form">
<div class="searchContainer">
<select name="mySelect" id="nameEx" class="allS">
    <option value="1" selected="selected">AND</option>
    <option value="2">EXCLUDE</option>
    <option value="3">OR</option>
</select>

<input class="textArea" id="name" name="name" placeholder="Name" style="margin: 0 auto;" type="text">
</div>
      <br>
  <div class="searchContainer">
<select name="mySelect" id="numberEx" class="allS">
    <option value="1" selected="selected">AND</option>
    <option value="2">EXCLUDE</option>
    <option value="3">OR</option>
</select>
    <input class="textArea" id="number" name="number" placeholder="Phone Number" style="margin: 0 auto;" type="text">
    </div>
   <br>
   <div class="searchContainer">
  <select name="mySelect" id="cityEx" class="allS">
    <option value="1" selected="selected">AND</option>
    <option value="2">EXCLUDE</option>
    <option value="3">OR</option>
</select>
<input class="textArea" id="city" name="city" placeholder="City" style="margin: 0 auto;" type="text">
    </div>
  </form>
  <div id="name_here" class="summaryParams"></div>
```

Here is my JS

```
$(".searchContainer").change(function () {
var str = '';
if ($('#name').val().length > 0)
    var str = $('#nameEx>option:selected').text() + ' Name: ' + $('#name').val();
$("#name_here").html(str);
});
$('#name_here').on('click', function() {document.getElementById("name").value = '';
 $("#name_here").html(""); 
});
```

PS The fields need to return distinct and seperate results.
Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I'm understanding your question correctly you could just use `each()` like this.

```
$(".searchContainer").each(function(){
    $(this).change(function(){
        // code to run on change on each .searchCOntainer
    });
});
```

I think this is close to what you want. [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/cwmxrn55/4/)

```
$(".searchContainer").each(function(){
    $(this).change(function () {
        var input = $(this).find('.textArea');
        var str1 = $('#name_here').text();
        var str2 = '';

        if (input.val().length > 0) {
            var str2 = $(this).find('option:selected').text() + ' ' + input.attr('placeholder') + ': ' + input.val();
        }

        $("#name_here").html(str1 + ' ' + str2);
    });
});


$('#name_here').on('click', function() {
  document.getElementById("name").value = '';
  $("#name_here").html("");
});
```

Comment: The #name is on the 8th line, and I must have left the bottom line out, its on the Fiddle. I will edit the question.

Comment: Thanks, It is close, however, I dont see how I could display the results of all three at the same time yet seperately.

Comment: I've updated my answer and updated the Fiddle. Is that what you want it to do?

Comment: Its really amazing, but is their any way to split the results into seperate parts, with each one being able to be clicked on to clear that specific field. Thanks again for all your help.

Answer (score 0):

You can pass a bound, named function as a handler. For example:

```
$('#some-element').on('change', doSomething.bind($('#some-other-element'), 'some-parameter' ));

function doSomething(someParameter) {
    // in this case, "this" now refers to $('#some-other-element')
    // so you could do something like $(this).value('hello world!')
    // and $('#some-other-element')'s value will be 'hello world'.

    // someParameter is now 'some-parameter'
}
```

Then, whenever you want to change the element, parameters, or whatever, next time you call it, just pass in a new element as the context, and whatever other parameters you want.

See the [MDN docs for Function.prototype.bind](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Function/bind) and [the jQuery docs for .on()](http://api.jquery.com/on/).

Another important thing to watch out for is that you want to pass in a function **reference** as the handler, not a function that is called.

## Edit (based on the comments)

Basically, to make the function "generic", you "extract" it as a named function (in this case, I named the function `doSomething`, but you can name it whatever you want.) Then you can pass in whatever parameters you need to and do something with them. Those parameters can be whatever you want.

This concept is called **separation of concerns**. A function should be able to do **one thing** (most of the time), and output something based on whatever information you pass or don't pass to it. In this case, the information is the parameters or elements.

Comment: @WhyEnBe, I would suggest reading the link I provided for "Function.prototype.bind", as well as reading the jQuery documentation for `.on()`.

Comment: @WhyEnBe, basically, to make the function generic, you "extract" it as a named function (in this case, I named the function `doSomething`, but you can name it whatever you want.) Then you can pass in whatever parameters you need to and do something with them. Those parameters can be whatever you want.

Comment: Thanks alot for all of your help, I guess I'm just not understanding how this would look with multiple possible fields.